# python compare two string like compare two documents in Word

Tags: python, text-analysis

I'd like to compare two paragraphs in character level, to see which words are modified.

Paragraphs to be compare:

```
t1 = '''1 Then was Jesus led up of the Spirit into the wilderness to be tempted of the devil.
2 And when he had fasted forty days and forty nights, he was afterward an hungred.
3 And when the tempter came to him, he said, If thou be the Son of God, command that these stones be made bread.
'''.splitlines(keepends=True)

t2 = '''1 Then Jesus was led up of the Spirit, into the wilderness, to be with God.
2 And when he had fasted forty days and forty nights, and had communed with God, he was afterwards an hungered, and was left to be tempted of the devil,
3 And when the tempter came to him, he said, If thou be the Son of God, command that these stones be made bread.
'''.splitlines(keepends=True)
```

When I try `difflib`, it works well in the first line, but it doesn't detect the difference in the second line.

```
>>> from difflib import *

>>> d = Differ()
>>> result = list(d.compare(t1,t2))
>>> for i in result:
...     print(i, end='')
```

### Result:

```
- 1 Then was Jesus led up of the Spirit into the wilderness to be tempted of the devil.
?        ----                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^  -  ----
+ 1 Then Jesus was led up of the Spirit, into the wilderness, to be with God.
?            ++++                      +                    +       ^^   ++
- 2 And when he had fasted forty days and forty nights, he was afterward an hungred.
+ 2 And when he had fasted forty days and forty nights, and had communed with God, he was afterwards an hungered, and was left to be tempted of the devil,
  3 And when the tempter came to him, he said, If thou be the Son of God, command that these stones be made bread.
```

Only the first paragraph has the desired output.

---

Even when I extract the second lines to compare

```
t1 = '''2 And when he had fasted forty days and forty nights, he was afterward an hungred.
'''.splitlines(keepends=True)

t2 = '''2 And when he had fasted forty days and forty nights, and had communed with God, he was afterwards an hungered, and was left to be tempted of the devil,
'''.splitlines(keepends=True)
d = Differ()
result = list(d.compare(t1,t2))
for i in result:
    print(i, end='')
```

### Result:

It doesn't show up which character is being modified, it shows that this line is being modified.

```
- 2 And when he had fasted forty days and forty nights, he was afterward an hungred.
+ 2 And when he had fasted forty days and forty nights, and had communed with God, he was afterwards an hungered, and was left to be
tempted of the devil,
```

---

But if I test with `SequenceMatcher` to compare the second lines, it seems to identify the modified characters.

```
p2_1 = '''2 And when he had fasted forty days and forty nights, he was afterward an hungred.'''
p2_2 = '''2 And when he had fasted forty days and forty nights, and had communed with God, he was afterwards an hungered, and was left to be tempted of the devil,'''
se = SequenceMatcher(None,p2_1, p2_2)
se.get_opcodes()
```

### Result:

```
[('equal', 0, 54, 0, 54),
 ('insert', 54, 54, 54, 81),
 ('equal', 54, 70, 81, 97),
 ('insert', 70, 70, 97, 98),
 ('equal', 70, 78, 98, 106),
 ('insert', 78, 78, 106, 107),
 ('equal', 78, 81, 107, 110),
 ('replace', 81, 82, 110, 152)]
```

## Question:

How do I compare the two paragraphs, that I can know which character is being modified? Or are there existing packages that I can use?

### This is my desired output

```
- 1 Then was Jesus led up of the Spirit into the wilderness to be tempted of the devil.
?        ----                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^  -  ----
+ 1 Then Jesus was led up of the Spirit, into the wilderness, to be with God.
?            ++++                      +                    +       ^^   ++
```

or anything like 
[image]

Comment: I am still a little confused. Can you give an example of the output you _do_ want?

Comment: @algerbrex Hi, I added the desired output.

Comment: Maybe there is something more to your problem, but can you not simply slice out the part you want from `results` and use that? `results[0:4]` gives me your desired output.